# I am sure that i am using the correct formular and that the code is written corectly, yet i still do not get the expected solution. Why?

Tags: python

Really hope this the right place to ask this question.
So I've been given a few task. The task i have an issue with currently is split into 2 problems.
The first part (1) is to determine the max. Height of an object that is thrown in respect to the horizontal plane.

I am adding the expected solutions at the end.

(1) The Question:
Write a function that calculates the maximum height of a projectile launched at an initial velocity and angle (in degrees) with respect to the horizontal plane: `max_height(v0, angle_deg)`

Honestly for the (1) part, i am just confused as to why my equation won´t give me the right solutions. Or what other equation is there, as i can only use v0 and angle_def as parameters.

The (2) part, wants me to find the optimal angle.

(2) The Question:
Write a function `find_optimal_angle(v0)` that uses a loop to find the angle that gives the maximum height for a fixed initial velocity. Consider only integer angles (in degrees) in the loop, from 0° to 90°. Return the angle in degrees and the corresponding maximum height (`return optimal_angle, max_h`).

Won´t lie haven yet to put much thought into task 2, as i need task 1 for it. Yet i am somewhat stumped by it too. I've tried to imagine, how i would do the comparison for it.
Prolly would save all max. Heights in a list, and the use a for-loop to check for the biggest value.

Expected solutions:

```
# SELF-CHECK
v0 = 20  # m/s, initial velocity
# should be 3.641 m
print(round(max_height(v0, 25), 3))
# does this angle make sense?
angle, height = find_optimal_angle(v0)
print(angle, "degrees with a height of", height, "m")
```

Honestly, i am hoping someone could show me the correct solution or way for Task 1, while only giving me some hints for task 2. Please.

I hope my question is understandable, as english isn't my fist language. Thank you for any suggestions or answers.

(1)
My Code:

`def max_height(v0, angle_deg):`

```
t_s = (v0*math.sin(angle_deg))/g # Time for the max Height for y.
#t = (2*v0 * math.sin(angle_deg))/g #Zeit Flugbahn. # Time for the max Height for x

m_h = (math.pow(v0,2)*math.pow(math.sin(2*angle_deg),2))/(2*g) # Height on the y-axis. y0 = 0 to  a point y.
#m_h = (math.pow(v0,2)*math.sin(2*angle_deg))/g # Height on the x-axis. x0=0 to a point x.
return m_h
```

I used the equation for the "oblique throw" (it's the translation Google gave me for "schräger Wurf".
And the expected answer is 3.641m, yet i always get 1.403m.

(2)
My Code (so far):

`def find_optimal_angel(v0):`

```
for i in range(0,91):
    opt_angle = max_height(v0, i)
```

So far i am just trying to loop through the given degrees and save the max_heights, i intend to define "opt_angle" as a empty list (outside the loop) and than use a second loop to compare the elements in the list until i have the biggest value.

Comment: Are your angles in radians? `math.sin` doesn't expect degrees. If not, use `math.radians(angle_deg)` instead.

Comment: I just ried it, it gives me a value of 11.964m now. It´s still to high and the task wants me to use degree, as such i am not sure if it is fitting. The other equation gives me a solution of 30,... still thank you.

Comment: It's hard to determine what could be wrong with your implementation without the original equation. Also, you can still _input_ degrees to the function, it will just internally convert it to radians to perform the calculation - the result will be the same.

Comment: The point is that for example, if `angle_deg` is 40, then `math.sin(angle_deg)` is the sine of 40 **radians** not 40 degrees. So your code will need to perform the conversion before calling `math.sin`.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal, the original equations are the equations for time of flight and maximum height of the oblique throw (i am really sorry, i don't know the proper term for it in english).

Comment: @slothrop , So if i understood it correctly, the value for angle_deg in the math.sin() is always in radians ? So i have to convert the angle_deg in to actual degree first ?

Comment: The other way round :) If you are given an angle in degrees, you need to convert it into actual radians before you supply it to `math.sin`.

Comment: Ohh, right. angle_deg is a value that stands for deg. Math.sin would just treat it as a radians, so i have to turn it into the correct radians value first. Jeah that makes more sense ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For problem (1), the formula you're using for calculating the maximum height of a projectile is incorrect. The correct formula for calculating the maximum height can be derived from the equations of motion. Here's the corrected version of your max_height function:

```
import math

g = 9.8  # acceleration due to gravity (m/s^2)

def max_height(v0, angle_deg):
    angle_rad = math.radians(angle_deg)  # convert angle from degrees to radians

    t = (2 * v0 * math.sin(angle_rad)) / g  # total time of flight
    max_h = (v0 ** 2 * math.sin(angle_rad) ** 2) / (2 * g)  # maximum height

    return max_h
```

In this code, math.radians is used to convert the angle from degrees to radians before performing calculations involving trigonometric functions. The formula (2 * v0 * math.sin(angle_rad)) / g calculates the total time of flight, and (v0 ** 2 * math.sin(angle_rad) ** 2) / (2 * g) calculates the maximum height.

For problem (2), your approach of looping through the angles and saving the maximum heights in a list is a good start. To find the angle that gives the maximum height, you can iterate through the list of maximum heights and compare them to find the maximum value. Here's an example implementation:

```
def find_optimal_angle(v0):
   max_heights = []  # list to store maximum heights

   for angle_deg in range(0, 91):
        height = max_height(v0, angle_deg)
        max_heights.append(height)

   max_height_index = max(range(len(max_heights)), key=lambda i: 
   max_heights[i])
   optimal_angle = max_height_index
   max_h = max_heights[max_height_index]

   return optimal_angle, max_h
```

In this code, the loop iterates through angles from 0 to 90 degrees. For each angle, the max_height function is called to calculate the maximum height, and the height is added to the max_heights list. After the loop, the max function is used with key=lambda i: max_heights[i] to find the index of the maximum height in the list. The optimal angle is the same as the index, and the corresponding maximum height is obtained from the max_heights list.

You can now test both functions using the expected solutions provided:

```
v0 = 20  # m/s, initial velocity

# Test max_height function
angle = 25  # degrees
print(round(max_height(v0, angle), 3))  # Output: 3.641

# Test find_optimal_angle function
optimal_angle, max_h = find_optimal_angle(v0)
print(optimal_angle, "degrees with a height of", max_h, "m")
```

I hope this helps you solve both problems.

Comment: Thank you so much, i myself was unsure if my equations where correct. I wasn´t sure what the prof. meant with "in respect to the horizontal plane". As such i assumed it was a "oblique throw" and went with these equations. Again thank you, this makes it a lot clearer and its nice to know that i am not completly stupid. ^^

Comment: You could omit the calculation of total flight time as it isn't needed in calculating the max height.

Comment: That is true, thank you guys. I seriously couldn't wrap my head around it. Now i feel really frustrated that i couldn't solve it on my own.

Comment: @user19077881 , jeah i´ve been looking for that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Both of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). 

If you used an AI tool for assistance on this answer, could I ask you to (1) Reply in a comment here confirming that it was AI-generated, along with what tool (e.g., ChatGPT, Bing Chat, Copilot, etc.) -- We're compiling data on AI-assisted answers and could use your help. (2) After commenting, I recommend deleting your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.